# What units should I use for lighting in a 3D rendering engine?

Tags: graphics, 3d, physics, lighting

In reading academic papers on rendering, graphics processing, lighting, etc..., I am finding a wide variety of units mentioned and used.

For example, [Bruneton's Atmospheric Scattering paper](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/Publications/Basilic/com.lmc.publi.PUBLI_Article@11e7cdda2f7_f64b69/article.pdf) seems to use candellas per square meter (cd/m^2), representing luminance. However, [Jensen's Night Model](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~henrik/papers/nightsky/nightsky.pdf) uses watts per square meter (W/m^2), implying irradiance. Other papers mention irradiance, luminance, illuminance, etc., with seemingly no common representation of the lighting calculations used. How then, can one even be sure that in implementing all of these papers, that the calculations will "play well" together?

To add to the confusion, most papers on adaptive tonemapping seem to forego units at all, merely recommending that pixels (referred to as luminance) be rendered in a log format (decibels). A decibel is useless without a reference intensity/power.

Which begs the question, what unit does a single pixel represent? When I calculate the "average luminance" of a scene by averaging the log-brightness of the pixels, what exactly am I calculating? The term ["luminance" itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) implies an area being illuminated and a solid angle for the source. This leads to two more questions: "What is the solid angle of the point source?" "What is the area of a pixel?"

My question is thus,
**What units should lighting in a 3d graphics engine be represented in to allow for proper, calibrated brightness control across a wide variety of light sources, from faint starlight to bright sunlight, and how does this unit relate to the brightness of individual pixels?**

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:  radiance, measured in `candela per square meter` (`cd/m^2`) is the appropriate unit.

---

Less briefly:  computer graphics is usually concerned with what things should look like to people.  The units that describe this are:

- "luminous flux" is measured in `lumens`, or `lm`, which are defined proportional to the total radiated power (in `watts`) of light at a particular wavelength.
- "luminous intensity" is measured in `candela`, or `cd`, which can be defined as `lumens per steradian` (`lm/sr`).

Intuitively, when you spread the same amount of energy over a larger area, it becomes proportionately less bright.  This yields two more quantities:

- "irradiance" is the luminous flux per unit area.  It is measured in `lm/m^2`, and is proportional to `W/m^2`.
- "radiance" is the luminous intensity per unit area.  It is measured in `cd/m^2`, or `lm/(sr.m^2)`.

---

Now, to answer your questions:

Each pixel represents a finite amount of solid angle from the camera, which is measured in `steradian`.  In the context of your question, the relevant area is the area of the *object being rendered*.

The radiance (measured in `cd/m^2`) represents surface brightness, and has the unique property that it is invariant along any unobstructed path of observation (which makes it the most appropriate quantity for a rendering engine).  The color of each pixel represents the *average radiance* over the solid angle occupied by that pixel.

Note that, by definition, a point source doesn't occupy any solid angle; its radiance is technically infinite.  Its irradiance is finite, though, and technically it should only contribute a finite (if potentially large) effect to a given pixel value.  In any case, if you want to directly render point sources, you will need to treat them differently from area sources, and deal with the problem that quantities other than radiance are not invariant over a given ray...

When Jensen et al's paper "A Physically-Based Night Sky Model" uses an irradiance-related `W/m^2` in a table of various sources of illumination, I would guess that their intention was to describe their relative contribution as averaged over the entire night sky, as abstracted from any visual details.

Finally, note that truly physically based models need to integrate over the observable spectrum in order to evaluate brightness and color.  Thus, such models must start out with a distribution of `watts` over visible wavelengths, and use the standard human colorimetric model to evaluate `lumens`.

Comment: Radiance's SI unit is the Watt per steradian per square meter, and is not concerned with human perception? I assume you're referring to luminance, which is cd/m^2, and is adjusted for human perception?

The confusion for me is what is the area represented? If I have a pixel seeing 10 cd/m^2, what is the square meter for in that measurement? 

Similarly, if I zoom in on a source so it so it covers more pixels, how does that change the brightness of the scene to my adaptive tone-mapper? Presumably you'd want the same average brightness regardless of the number of pixels covered by the source.

Comment: Sorry, I composed the units section partly from CG literature and partly from colorimetric/physical references.  I will recheck my references and figure out how to reword the answer in a bit...

Comment: If you had a camera with a finite aperture, then the `m^2` would refer to the area of its aperture.  An idealized, CG camera takes the limit of the local light distribution as the aperture shrinks to zero, without worrying about little things like diffraction and photon statistics...

Comment: So then, if I have a light source that is 100 cd/sr*m^2, I can arbitrarily define a pixel to be a "1 steradian unit", then I can multiply every pixel by my virtual camera aperture area to get a value for the current pixel?

Comment: No, the pixels all have well-defined solid angles.  Also, your units are redundant -- I assume you meant `100 cd/m^2`, or perhaps `100 lm/(sr*m^2)`

Comment: Again, your virtual camera doesn't *have* an aperture area -- it's an idealized point, like a point light source.  The radiance (using CG parlance, measured in `lm/(sr*m^2)`) tells you the distribution of visible light over both area *and* angle...

Comment: Think of it by analogy to velocity, which is the derivative of position with respect to time.  Position has units of `meters`, and velocity has units of `meters/second`.  Does it make sense to ask how much time your speedometer has?

Comment: Actually, that's a bit of a bad analogy for a CG camera, since pixels are arguably a discrete decomposition of the solid angle occupied by the camera view.  Also, I'm afraid I'm not tracking your reasoning very well... I'll take a break and try to return to this later with a fresh mind.

Answer (score -1):

The SI unit for brightness is the [Candela per square metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela_per_square_metre) so if your wanting to represent actual physical quantities it would be hard to argue against using that. As for how this unit relates to the brightness of an individual pixel that would be a function of the brightness at that part of the illumination source represented in the pixels viewing area combined with contributions from elsewhere in the scene as calculated by the engine - presumably this would very completely depending on the renderer.